# Python - Saving an image downloaded from a request

Tags: python, image, python-requests

I'm trying to save an image I'm downloading from an API request. I've tested this in postman and the response downloads the image (doesn't give a URL to the image). What I'm trying to do is save the image response that I get but I'm not sure how to do this. Does some one have a suggestion for what might work here?

```
atturl = 'https://api.website.net/job/' + str(custs['uuid']) + '/task/' + str(custs['tasks'][q]) + '/attachment/' + str(custs['tasks'][q]['attachments'][qt])
taskresp = requests.get(atturl, headers=headers)
picOutFile = open('test.jpg', "w")
picOutFile.write(taskresp)
picOutFile.close
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the file in binary mode and write the response content (bytes).

```
import io

with io.open('test.jpg', "wb") as pic_out_file:
    pic_out_file.write(taskresp.content)
```

See [Binary response Content](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content) in the Requests documentation.

Comment: Is there any benefits of using `io.open()` instead of just common `open()`? Seem to make same magic

Comment: @Andersson yes: Python 2/3 compatibility.